# How to get value from string using a '-' delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in my table that looks like this:

```
Row    Scheme
-----------------------------
001    NULL
002    NULL
003    Scheme1-0.50-Point
003    Scheme1-0.50-Point
004    NULL
005    Scheme1-1.00-Point
006    1_N/A
```

The `scheme` column's values are concenated like this:

```
SchemeName + '-' + Points + '-' + Units
```

I want output using T-SQL to separate that string using the `-` delimiter:

```
Row    Scheme                Name       Point    Unit
------------------------------------------------------
001                  NULL       NULL     NULL    NULL    
002                  NULL       NULL     NULL    NULL    
003    Scheme1-0.50-Point    Scheme1     0.50    Point
003    Scheme1-0.50-Point    Scheme1     0.50    Point
004                  NULL       NULL     NULL    NULL
005    Scheme1-1.00-Point    Scheme1     1.00    Point
006                 1_N/A       NULL     NULL    NULL
```

Comment: If it's possible, try changing your design.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `XML node` method that could help you :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Row], [Scheme],
    a.value ('/A[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [NAME],
    a.value ('/A[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [POINT],
    a.value ('/A[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [UNIT]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [Row], [Scheme], 
         CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(ISNULL([Scheme], ''), '-', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS [Scheme1] 
     FROM <table_name>) A 
CROSS APPLY 
    Scheme1.nodes ('/A') as split(a)
```